# JavaFx - Change cursor does not work

Tags: javafx, treeview, cursor

I'm new working with javafx. The idea is show the WAIT cursor when I change between nodes in a treeview (this change requires some long operations).

I'm trying the following:

```
    // ACTION treeitem selection
    treeview.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<TreeItem>() {

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends TreeItem> paramObservableValue, final TreeItem oldValue,
                final TreeItem newValue) {


           // CURSOR CHANGE 
           tilepane.getScene().setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);


           Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                // SOME LONG OPERATION
                tilepane.getScene().setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);     

                }
            });

        }

    });
```

But while the log operations are executing, the cursor does not change.

(tilepane is the pane where I want to show the wait cursor)

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaFX buttons don't disable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26953633/javafx-buttons-dont-disable) (and many others)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Long Operations should **not** take place in the GUI (JavaFX) Thread. For these operations we have the [Task](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) and the [Service](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Service.html) classes at hand.
2. `Platform.runLater()` does not do your work in a background Thread, instead it runs the given Runnable on the next scene pulse on the GUI Thread.

So, if you chose to use a Task for your long running operations you have some handy places where to change the cursor:

- [setOnScheduled](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#setOnScheduled-javafx.event.EventHandler-) will be called right before the Task is going to start its background work.
- [setOnSucceeded](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#setOnSucceeded-javafx.event.EventHandler-) will be called right after the Task has successfully completed its background work.